# Task module window not closing after performing Action.OpenUrl action through button

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have a MS Teams bot. I have added a task module which pops up a window. 
On that window, I have a button "Gethelp" which performs **Action.OpenUrl** action. Now when I click on "Gethelp" it opens up the mentioned url in browser but the task module window gets hanged (We can't close the task module window and have to restart MS Teams). Does anyone know how to handle this?

Comment: Can you show how you're invoking the task module?

Comment: Please follow this document and improve your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @madhukarchaure04 I tried OpenUrl from TaskModule and it works as expected for me. Could you please share the logs to [microsoftteamsdevATmicrosoftDOTcom]. You could get them by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Shift+1. Logs will be downloaded to the default downloads folder.